# Mule 4 secure property placeholder not working

Tags: security, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, property-placeholder, mule4

This is my config  where i have defined my properties file ie dev.properties which has some encrypted values. I have defined my secure property placeholder but its not working

```
<global-property doc:name="Global Property" doc:id="7080a89f-d39c-485d-99c4-b35337ab62c4" name="env" value="dev" />
    <global-property doc:name="Global Property" doc:id="5d1fb026-a34f-490f-9b50-7a9bcb5cdf83" name="enc.key" value="password" />
    <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties"
        doc:id="7448fcf9-e3ef-41b4-879e-9551ab99aa29" file="properties/${env}.properties" />
        <secure-properties:config name="Secure_Properties_Config" doc:name="Secure Properties Config" doc:id="0bbad3ed-42bb-4e13-bc88-e9c1fc6d21f4" file="properties/${env}.properties" key="${enc.key}"  >
    </secure-properties:config>
```

I have encrypted using the value password with AES algorithm. However its not able to decrypt those values with the config provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are loading the same properties file using `configuration-properties` and then again using `secure-properties`. Only load the file once using s`ecure-properties` if it contains `secure-properties`.

Second, you need to use `${secure:myProp.someProp}` syntax to read secure properties, rather than just `${myProp.someProp}`

If you are using the same file for secure and non-secure properties, you still have to use `${secure:myProp.someProp}` for the non-secure properties.

Therefore it is best practice to split your property files into `${env}.properties` for non-secure and `${env}-secure.properties` for secure properties. Then you can use configuration-properties ${env}.properties and secure-properties for `${env}-secure.properties`.

If you are getting a specific error, please update the question with details.

Comment: Thanks @ryan its working after adding the ${secure:myProp.someProp} keyword .